# How to write a common code to display many picturebox in vb.net 2.0 ?

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

```
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Public Class Form1
Dim delay As Integer = 200
Dim i As Integer = 1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    While i <= 5

        PictureBox1.Visible = True
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
        Sleep(delay)
        PictureBox1.Visible = False


        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        PictureBox2.Refresh()
        Sleep(delay)
        PictureBox2.Visible = False


        PictureBox3.Visible = True
        PictureBox3.Refresh()
        Sleep(delay)
        PictureBox3.Visible = False


        PictureBox4.Visible = True
        PictureBox4.Refresh()
        Sleep(delay)
        PictureBox4.Visible = False


        PictureBox5.Visible = True
        PictureBox5.Refresh()
        Sleep(delay)
        PictureBox5.Visible = False

        i = i + 1
        If i = 6 Then
            i = 1
        End If

    End While
End Sub
```

i wrote the above code. it's working. but the following code is not not working. i want to minimize the code. i want to use 20 picture box. instead of the above code i want to use small code but it will do the same work. please help me.

```
  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    While i <= 5
        Dim pic As PictureBox
        Dim matches() As Control

        matches = Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox" & i.ToString(), True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Label Then
            pic = DirectCast(matches(0), PictureBox)
            pic.Visible = True
            pic.Refresh()
            Sleep(delay)
            pic.Visible = False
        End If

        i = i + 1
        If i = 6 Then
            i = 1
        End If
    End While
End Sub
  End Class
```

Comment: "Not working" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: if i click button1  i'm getting the correct output. but if i press button2 then i'm not getting same output.. actually i want to minimize the button1 coding. so i used the button2 coding. please help me.

Comment: You are doing many things fundamentally wrong.  Calling Sleep() and running loops that never quit are poison to programs that display UI.  And yes, it will look like it is "not working", the UI will simply stop updating and show no sign of progress.   Educate yourself instead of randomly trying code, it just isn't that easy to guess at.

Comment: extremely sorry...  i wrote wrong code ... sorry ...thank u all...   correct code                                                                                              matches = Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox" & i.ToString(), True)
            If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is PictureBox Then

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    While i <= 5
        Dim pic As PictureBox
        Dim matches() As Control

        matches = Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox" & i.ToString(), True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is PictureBox Then
            pic = DirectCast(matches(0), PictureBox)
            pic.Visible = True
            pic.Refresh()
            Wait(delay)
            pic.Visible = False
        End If

        i = i + 1
        If i = 6 Then
            i = 1
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

this code is correct... sorry i wrote wrong code 1st time.. now it's correct.. thank u all..